# How do I get the elements/objects inside a FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm trying to access the contents of a `FlowDocument` (of a `RichTextBox`). I wanna do this because I want to convert the contents to a UBB formatted `string` (yea, the old forum formated text). Is there a way to get the contents of the `FlowDocument`'s contents:

I know that via [`FlowDocuments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.blocks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property you can get the `Blocks` inside the `FlowDocument`, which are itself `BlockUIContainer`, `List`, `Paragraph`, `Section` or `Table` objects, as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued). However, if I want the [`LogicalChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.logicalchildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of [`Paragraph`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example, its protected and thus inaccessable. So.. This is not the way to go. What is? (I did not find another way, yet.)

Also, I know about converting the contents of a `FlowDocument` to XAML, etc. But the converters I found, did not include image objects and some other objects I find usefull and are displayed by the `RichTextBox`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah! I found the solution...

- [`BlockUIContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has [`Child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer.child%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which in return can contain everything else (as long as it inherents from `UIElement`)
- It's called [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on a `Paragraph`. This returns a collection of [`Inline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- For [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) its called [`ListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.listitems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This contains a collection of [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which in return contains [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued), thus either of these.
- A [`Sections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.section%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also contains `Blocks`
- [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has [`RowGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.rowgroups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has a collection of [`TableRowGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablerowgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc. etc. etc.

I've been dumb not to think about the `ContentPropertyAttribute`...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use XmlDocument?

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox.Document));
```

There are interesting possiblities e. g. using selection of nodes with xpath.